# does this c++ code have memory leaks?

Tags: c++, libevent

I'm trying to understand this `Libevent` c++ code I got from [this page](http://incpp.blogspot.com/2009/04/libevent.html).
I'm a bit confused - am I correct to think that this code might have memory leaks?

It seems like `ConnectionData` pointer is created in `on_connect()` callback, but `delete()` is only called on bad read or after write is complete.
What if connection was `accept()`ed  - but there were no reads or writes? so is that pointer just stays in daemon memory?

```
#include <event.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <iostream>

// Read/write buffer max length
static const size_t MAX_BUF = 512;

typedef struct {
    struct event ev;
    char         buf[MAX_BUF];
    size_t       offset;
    size_t       size;
} ConnectionData;

void on_connect(int fd, short event, void *arg);
void client_read(int fd, short event, void *arg);
void client_write(int fd, short event, void *arg);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Check arguments
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cout << "Run with options: <ip address> <port>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // Create server socket
    int server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_sock == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create socket" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    sockaddr_in sa;
    int         on      = 1;
    char      * ip_addr = argv[1];
    short       port    = atoi(argv[2]);

    sa.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port         = htons(port);
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(ip_addr);

    // Set option SO_REUSEADDR to reuse same host:port in a short time
    if (setsockopt(server_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on)) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set option SO_REUSEADDR" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Bind server socket to ip:port
    if (bind(server_sock, reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&sa), sizeof(sa)) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to bind server socket" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Make server to listen
    if (listen(server_sock, 10) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to make server listen" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Init events
    struct event evserver_sock;
    // Initialize
    event_init();
    // Set connection callback (on_connect()) to read event on server socket
    event_set(&evserver_sock, server_sock, EV_READ, on_connect, &evserver_sock);
    // Add server event without timeout
    event_add(&evserver_sock, NULL);

    // Dispatch events
    event_dispatch();

    return 0;
}

// Handle new connection {{{
void on_connect(int fd, short event, void *arg) 
{
    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t   len = 0;

    // Accept incoming connection
    int sock = accept(fd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&client_addr), &len);
    if (sock < 1) { 
        return; 
    }

    // Set read callback to client socket
    ConnectionData * data = new ConnectionData;
    event_set(&data->ev, sock, EV_READ, client_read, data);
    // Reschedule server event
    event_add(reinterpret_cast<struct event*>(arg), NULL);
    // Schedule client event
    event_add(&data->ev, NULL);
}
//}}}

// Handle client request {{{
void client_read(int fd, short event, void *arg)
{
    ConnectionData * data = reinterpret_cast<ConnectionData*>(arg);
    if (!data) {
        close(fd);
        return;
    }
    int len = read(fd, data->buf, MAX_BUF - 1);
    if (len < 1) {
        close(fd);
        delete data;
        return;
    }
    data->buf[len] = 0;
    data->size     = len;
    data->offset   = 0;
    // Set write callback to client socket
    event_set(&data->ev, fd, EV_WRITE, client_write, data);
    // Schedule client event
    event_add(&data->ev, NULL);
}
//}}}

// Handle client responce {{{
void client_write(int fd, short event, void *arg)
{
    ConnectionData * data = reinterpret_cast<ConnectionData*>(arg);
    if (!data) {
        close(fd);
        return;
    }
    // Send data to client
    int len = write(fd, data->buf + data->offset, data->size - data->offset);
    if (len < data->size - data->offset) {
        // Failed to send rest data, need to reschedule
        data->offset += len;
        event_set(&data->ev, fd, EV_WRITE, client_write, data);
        // Schedule client event
        event_add(&data->ev, NULL);
    }
    close(fd);
    delete data;
}
//}}}
```

Comment: yeah - great - why all the down-votes. Person has asked a valid question?

Comment: i'm new to c++ -this is first time I hear about valgrind. Besides - this is more of a logic question.

Comment: Read the downvote button text, especially the part mentioning *effort*

Comment: PlasmaHH - I've read the code and I understood it - but I'm very new to c++ and thus  it's very important for me to have an external confirmation from experienced developers confirming the problem. I've certainly done my research.

Comment: for second opinions, there is codereview.SE. If you have a certain problem like memory leaks, SO expects you to do your research and at least try to find a way to check if something has memory leaks (and it would be surprising if by googling you wont find a way to check for memory leaks). If you then apply those and ask here "why does this code [[SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)] has a memory leak as shown by valgrind" is more appropriate.

Comment: Traditionally, when the socket closes, `read` occurs and returns `0`, triggering the `delete`. Basically _all_ `select`/`read` loops in POSIX-like code do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for event_set](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-1.4/doxygen/html/event_8h.html#a24235e12d151db1782f792e14c83cf82) says that the only valid event types are `EV_READ` or `EV_WRITE`, but the callback will be invoked with `EV_TIMEOUT`, `EV_SIGNAL`, `EV_READ`, or `EV_WRITE`. The documentation is not clear, but I expect the read callback will be invoked when the socket is closed by the client. I expect the `delete` in the failure branch in `client_read` will handle this situation.

Note that that is only the case if the client sends a `FIN` or `RST` packet. A client could establish a connection and leave it open forever. For this reason, this code should be modified to have a timeout (perhaps via [event_once](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-1.4/doxygen/html/event_8h.html#a450e7c610ac0e321168f036350c36d54)) and require the client send a message within that timeout.

Comment: I've just asked on #libevent channel - and they said that EV_READ always triggers - event when client cuts the cord after accept(). So EV_READ callback will reliably execute. So I think we can conclude this code should not leak.